# How to get rid of null value in JSON with stedolan/jq?

Tags: json, null, key, jq

The real problem is a bit more complicated, but I have problems with the following json formatting.

Command:
`echo '[{"user":"a","title":"aaa"},{"user":"b","title":null}]' | jq '.[]'`

Out:

```
{
  "user": "a",
  "title": "aaa"
}
{
  "user": "b",
  "title": null
}
```

I want to:

```
{
  "user": "a",
  "title": "aaa"
}
{
  "user": "b"
}
```

So I do:
`echo '[{"user":"a","title":"aaa"},{"user":"b","title":null}]' | jq '.[]|{user:.user, title:(.title//empty)}'`

Result:

```
{
  "user": "a",
  "title": "aaa"
}
```

Sadly whole latter object removed. if you know some good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct approach would be simply to delete the unwanted key where it occurs, e.g. by:

```
map( if .title == null then del(.title) else . end)
```

#### Using `walk/1`

If you want to do this globally (i.e, wherever .title is null, no matter where the object occurs):

```
walk(if type == "object" and .title == null then del(.title) else . end)
```

This can be tidied up a bit using the generic function, `when/2`:

```
 def when(p;q): if p? // false then q else . end;
```

Now we can simply write:

```
 walk( when(.title == null; del(.title)) )
```

### The whole nine yards

```
def when(p;q): if p? // false then q else . end; 

walk( when(type=="object"; with_entries( select(.value != null ))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Excuse my ignorance, but I try to understand your code properly, would take a little more time

Comment: I hope you find the investment worthwhile!

Answer (score 1):

*alternatively*, the same ask could be achieved using a unix walk-path based unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ JSN='[{"user":"a","title":"aaa"},{"user":"b","title":null}]'
bash $ <<<$JSN jtc -w'[title]:<>n:' -p
[
   {
      "title": "aaa",
      "user": "a"
   },
   {
      "user": "b"
   }
]
bash $
```

that will remove all (if there are multiple) records `"title":null`
if there's a need to remove all `null` values (not only scoped by `title`) then the walk-path `-w'<>n:'` to be used

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations